# delegating between classes - best practice

Tags: c#, ooad

I have C# component that has a class as below:

```
    namespace SharedComponent{
       class TestResult {
           //several members
       }
    }
```

In another existing C# application I am referencing this component and I need to instantiate this same class but with an additional identifier as below.

```
    namespace ClientApplication {
      class TestResult 
      { 
             //exact same members as above including methods
             //actually the shared component class was created by gleaming 
             //that from this application!
             int PersonID; //additional identifier
                  //not suitable to have in the shared component
      }
  }
```

In the client application there are several methods that rely on the additional identifier. So it is very tempting for me to emulate a copy constructor and create this object and fill in the additional parameter. This way I can use the existing functions as they are with minimal changes to the class.

Another way could be to add the rest of the details as a reference to the client side implementation.

```
 namespace ClientApplication {
     class TestResult {
      SharedComponent.TestResult trshared = new SharedComponent.TestResult()
       //but this warrants I have my class methods to delegate 
       //to the sharedcomponent throughout ; example below

      internal bool IsFollowUp(ClientApplication.TestResult prevTest)
      {
        //a similar method is being used
                //where a function takes the class object as parameter
                trshared.IsFollowUp(prevTest.trshared);
      }

      int PersonID; //additional identifier

   }
}
```

Which option is better? What is the best practice in this regard?

Environment: VS2008, C#, WinXP/Win7

Comment: Can the client app class just inherit from the original?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like your ClientApplication.TestResult "is a" SharedComponent.TestResult.  Assuming that SharedComponent.TestResult is not sealed, you can extend from that class.  This way you do not have to copy paste code.  If you are also able to modify SharedComponent.TestResult, then you can declare the methods to be virtual, and override their behavior in your ClientApplication.TestResult.

```
class TestResult : SharedComponent.TestResult
{
    int PersonId { get; set; }

    override bool IsFollowUp(ClientApplication.TestResult prevTest)
    {
          // Your own implementation or trivial (base.IsFollowUp(ClientApplication.TestResult.prevTest.trShared)
    }
}
```

If you cannot change the method to be virtual in SharedComponent.TestResult, then you can use the keyword "new" in the derived class.